# how to remove this skip to content wordpress error?

Tags: wordpress

I am facing this problem using my wordpress how to fix it?

[image]

```
The requested URL /usama/wordpress/about-us/2019/11/07/india-lost-a-world-cup/ was not found on this server.
```

Comment: Any update on this question? because I am also facing same issue.

Comment: @vikash Singh Do you have any suggestion for this?

Answer (score 1):

It's not a bug, it's a feature!

That "skip to content" link makes it easier to navigate with the keyboard. If you press TAB on your keyboard that link appears and if you select it, the focus skips to the content and you don`t have to TAB through the whole header.

But your css is not loading properly, so the "skip to content link" is visible.

Try to set the the "Wordpress-URL" and the "Website URL" to the right values in the settings.

Regards Tom

Answer (score 0):

Adding the following code to the `wp-config.php` file may fix the problem:

```
if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_SSL']))
{
 $_SERVER['SERVER_PORT']=443; 
 $_SERVER['HTTPS']='on'; 
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This error is very disturbing. I had the same error and I fixed it with the code below:

```
define( 'CONCATENATE_SCRIPTS', false );
```

Add the code to wp-config.php file. It's a css error. Also check your CDN configuration. I turned my off (Godaddy Managed WordPress Hosting). My site is back and running smoothly.

Hope this helps.

Thanks

Comment: Wouldn't this break other aspects of the site? it seems like a solution that worked by chance but it has other non-intended consequences. Unless it was added as an answer to mess/break other sites :/